# Создание веток в PyCharm 2020*

Tags: git, pycharm

Всем привет!

При обновлении PyCharm с версии 2019* на версию 2020* заметил изменение при переключении веток.

В 2019* переключение происходило через **Checkout As...**:

[image]

И можно было сразу видеть, от какой ветки отпочковалась локальная ветка:

[image]

Обновление (**git pull**, **Ctrl + T**) из удаленной ветки происходит. Все было хорошо.

В версиях 2020* произошли изменения. Переключение происходит через **New Branch from Selected...**:

[image]

При этом к локальной ветке удаленная ветка не подцепляется:

[image]

Соответственно, **git pull**, **Ctrl + T** не работают. Приходится руками создавать set-upstream.

Плагин Git перевключал.

Так и должно быть? Или я что-то неправильно делаю?